# How do you get all the businesses within 10 miles of my location in Swift using corelocation?

Tags: swift, core-location, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to get all the businesses within 10 miles of my location in Swift. I tried using the geocoder from CoreLocation and GoogleMaps and it gives me random places but I just want to see all the businesses near my location. Is that possible or do I have to cut my search to restaurants, cafe, etc.?

Comment: What's a business? A restaurant? A motorcycle repair shop? A stockbroker? A real estate agent? A day care center? A programmer?

Comment: @matt yes everything that is considered as a business by google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this google api for getting nearby businesses

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY

also you can see all available keywords from
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types

for using multiple keywords simultaneously

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=atm%7Chospital&key=YOUR_API_KEY

add keywords seperated by %7C

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20704267)

Comment: thank you for the advice :)

add keywords seperated by %7C